# Getting facebook name from id using graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get a facebook user details using the Graph API:

http://graph.facebook.com/[facebook_id]/

But I'm getting this response:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104,
      "fbtrace_id": "AkJ8KoQS45g"
   }
}
```

I am able to access only the picture edge, but not any other data.

I don't have an app, and I don't want any access token, just the visible information about the username, just as can be seen by accessing http://www.facebook.com/759606364077706 but with an API.

Comment: Not possible. You have to use an access token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook no longer returns public profile without an active access token. Strangely though `/[facebook-id]/picture/` edge still works without any access token.

You can play around with Graph APIs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).

Comment: Isn't there a "mock token" or something? It is totally irrational.. I can just parse the HTML of the page without logging in to facebook, but thats exactly what the Graph API is for.

Comment: I wouldn't not say that it is completely irrational. Perhaps it was the privacy issues that they shut down the feature.